# How can I check if handlebars are straight?

Tags: motorcycle, alignment, tips-and-tricks, handlebars

My motorbike took a pretty hard hit and I am suspecting that my steering is crooked. How can I check if my handlebars are straight/does not deviate from its originally intended shape?

Comment: Is it a single piece handlebar or "clip on" style handlebars?

Comment: Single piece motocross-style handlebar.

Comment: Are you just focusing on the handle bars themselves or is this all part of a total answer toward your other question posted.

Comment: @spicetraders This question here focuses on the bars themselves. The other focuses on steering.

Comment: Hold the handle bars straight and see if the bike goes straight. Also, I mean, does it *feel* off? That's all that matters: safety and feel. So if it feels off, trust your feeling, and adjust until it doesn't. If you've been riding your bike for a while, your brain is essentially keeping it straight with a well-trained neural control feedback loop (colloquially, "second nature"); your feeling is probably correct, even if you can't put a finger on it.

Answer (score 5):

Since your motorcycle has handlebars that are a single piece, remove them from the motorcycle and remove all accessories from them.

Check for obvious signs of bending such as cracked paint or metal. If these are present, the bars are definitely bent.

The bars should be symmetrical, so you'll want to get an angle finder. You can place it on each bend of the handlebar and compare the angle with the same bend on the opposite side. If they do not closely agree, then something is bent somewhere.

Replacement aftermarket handlebars are generally not very expensive, so the easiest course for correcting bent handlebars is replacement.

Here is the type of tool you need

[image]

Comment: How closely is closely? :)

Answer (score 2):

**Find a flat surface**

1. Take all of the accessories off of you handlebars, strip them clean of any additional item.
2. Set the handlebars on the flat surface.
3. You should have 4 points of the handlebars that are hitting the flat surface.
4. If you have 4 points all hitting the flat surface at the same time, you handlebars are straight.  If you DO NOT have 4 points touching the flat surface continue to step 5.
5. If you have only 3 points on the handlebar touching the flat surface at the same time you; rock the handlebars on the two highest points. You may be able to figure out how they are bent.  The point being, they are bent.

Granite countertops are good flat surfaces.  Sometimes within .005 inches.  Cement slabs frequently are not good, having too much variance in height.